# Why is the CAN signal sampling type irregular in Vector Canoe?

Tags: vector, canoe, canalyzer

As shown in the canoe graphic in the figure, the signal of the message has an irregular period.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3MZK.jpg)

Why is Δt not constant in the trace and
why does the signal also look irregular in the graphic?

Not only the messages shown in the figure, but all can messages show this pattern for the same time period.

Comment: The messages are received at those timestamps because they have been sent at those timestamps. Why should they be "regular"?

Comment: Each controller has its own Tx period(timestamps). If so, isn't regular correct?

Comment: Each controller may _try_ to send something with fixed time slices. But what ends up at the bus is a different topic. The bus has to be idle, there may be arbitration issues and so on. All that influences when a message is really transmitted over the bus.